# react native if else condition in render()

Tags: node.js, react-native, if-statement

Hello everyone i am learning REACT-NATIVE from last two months , i got a small issue with if-else condition render method ,while i am executing the code if condition is not working properly .
Can you please tell me the solution

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Image, Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput, Button, TouchableHighlight, Alert,
  TouchableOpacity, ScrollView, ColorPropType, FlatList, SectionList, Dimensions, AsyncStorage,
  Keyboard,
} from 'react-native';

import axios from 'axios';
import GlobalStore from '../GlobalStore';
const API_URL = GlobalStore.BASE_URL;



var ACCESS_TOKEN = 'access_token';



export default class LogInScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'LogIn',
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: '#03A9F4',
    },
    headerTintColor: '#fff',
    headerTitleStyle: {
      fontWeight: 'bold',
    },
  };
  /* *********** Code Starts Here ******************  */
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      error: '',
      userId: '',
      user_id: '',
      mobile: '',
      password: '',
      Token: '',


    };

  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.get_Id();
    this.getToken();
  }
  // get id from asyncStorage
  async get_Id() {
    try {
      const userId = await AsyncStorage.getItem('USER_ID') // (STORAGE_KEY)

      if (userId !== '' || userId !== null) {
        this.setState({ userId: userId })
        console.log('profile get_id id: =>', userId)
        // this.getUserDetails(userId)
      } else {
        console.log('profile get_id id: => user_id=null')
        Alert.alert('No user profile found LogIn Now ' + this.props.navigation.navigate('LogIn'))
      }

    } catch (error) {
      alert('Failed to load profile get_Id() user_id.')
    }
  }



  async storeToken(accessToken) {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem(ACCESS_TOKEN, accessToken);
      this.getToken();
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('LogIn AsyncStorage Error: ' + error.message);
    }
  }


  async getToken() {
    try {
      let token = await AsyncStorage.getItem(ACCESS_TOKEN);
      this.setState({ Token: token })
      console.log("LogIn Get token is :" + token);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("something went wrong in getToken LogIn page")
    }
  }

  async removeToken() {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.removeItem(ACCESS_TOKEN);
      this.getToken();
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("some thing went wrong removeToken LogIn page")
    }
  }



  validate_Fields = () => {
    const { mobile, password } = this.state
    if (mobile == "") {
      Alert.alert("please enter Mobile Number");
      return false
    }
    if (mobile.length < 10) {
      Alert.alert("please enter 10 digit Mobile Number");
      return false
    }
    if ((password === "" && password.length < 6)) {
      Alert.alert("please enter password minimum length should be 6");
      return false
    }
    return true
  }



  // logIn function  
  logInUser() {
    if (this.validate_Fields()) {
      const { mobile, password } = this.state;
      this.setState({ error: '', loading: true });
      // NOTE HTTP is insecure, only post to HTTPS in production apps

      axios.post(API_URL + '/usersapi/user_LogIn', {
        mobile_no: mobile,
        password: password
      })
        .then((response) => {
          // console.log(JSON.stringify(response));         
          let accessToken = response.data.TOKEN;
          this.storeToken(accessToken);
          console.log("dataToken-LogIn:" + accessToken);
          Alert.alert('LogIn Successfully ' + this.props.navigation.navigate('Profile', { accessToken }));
          // Alert.alert('LogIn Successfully ' + + this.props.navigation.navigate('Profile'));
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
          this.removeToken();
          Alert.alert(' Login Failed try again , If you do not have an account, sign up first !');

        });
    }
  }


  render() {
    if (this.state.userId !== '' || this.state.userId !== null) {
      return (
        // console.log('if block - No data found profile => LogIn now.:' + this.state.userId)
        // Alert.alert('Please LogIn Now')
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <View style={styles.ifContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.formHeader}>Thank you - you are already logedIn Got to</Text>
            <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.buttonContainer, styles.greenButton]} onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')}>
              <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Home</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>

            <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.buttonContainer, styles.blueButton]} onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Profile')}>
              <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Profile</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </View>
        // Alert.alert('You are already LogedIn ' + this.props.navigation.navigate('Profile'))
      )

    } else {
      return (
        <View styel={styles.container}>
          <View style={{ alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
            <Text style={styles.formHeader}>LogIn</Text>
            <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
              <TextInput style={styles.inputs}
                type='number'
                value={this.state.mobile}
                name="mobile"
                maxLength={10}
                placeholder="mobile"
                keyboardType="numeric"
                underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
                onChangeText={(mobile) => this.setState({ mobile })} />
              <Image style={styles.inputIcon} source={{ uri: 'https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/android.png' }} />
            </View>

            <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
              <TextInput style={styles.inputs}
                type='password'
                value={this.state.password}
                name="password"
                placeholder="Password"
                secureTextEntry={true}
                underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
                onChangeText={(password) => this.setState({ password })} />
              <Image style={styles.inputIcon} source={{ uri: 'https://img.icons8.com/color/40/000000/password.png' }} />
            </View>

            <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.buttonContainer, styles.greenButton]} onPress={() => { this.logInUser() }}>
              <Text style={styles.buttonText}>LogIn</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>


            <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.buttonContainer, styles.blueButton]} onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Register')}>
              <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Register</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>



          </View >
        </View>
      )
    }
  }// Render Ends 

} // Class Ends 




const resizeMode = 'center';
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#DCDCDC',
  },
  formHeader: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginBottom: 20,
    fontSize: 30,
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    color: 'black',
  },
  inputContainer: {
    borderBottomColor: '#F5FCFF',
    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
    borderRadius: 30,
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    width: 300,
    height: 45,
    marginBottom: 20,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    shadowColor: "#808080",
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 0,
      height: 2,
    },
    shadowOpacity: 0.25,
    shadowRadius: 3.84,
    elevation: 5,
  },
  inputs: {
    height: 45,
    marginLeft: 16,
    borderBottomColor: '#FFFFFF',
    flex: 1,
    fontSize: 20,
  },
  inputIcon: {
    width: 30,
    height: 30,
    marginRight: 15,
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  buttonContainer: {
    height: 45,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginBottom: 20,
    width: 300,
    borderRadius: 30,
    backgroundColor: 'transparent'
  },
  greenButton: {
    backgroundColor: "#00a63f",
    shadowColor: "#808080",
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 0,
      height: 9,
    },
    shadowOpacity: 0.50,
    shadowRadius: 12.35,
    elevation: 19,
  },
  blueButton: {
    backgroundColor: "#4e8bd1",
    shadowColor: "#808080",
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 0,
      height: 9,
    },
    shadowOpacity: 0.50,
    shadowRadius: 12.35,
    elevation: 19,
  },
  buttonText: {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textShadowColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75)',
    textShadowOffset: { width: -1, height: 1 },
    textShadowRadius: 10
  },
  bgImage: {
    flex: 1,
    resizeMode,
    position: 'absolute',
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  }

});







LogInScreen.navigationOptions = {
  title: 'LogIn',
};
```

please check the code and let me know if i wrote anything wrong in the code .

Comment: Can you provide more details of what is not working properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. change if condition in render from or  to and:

   ```
   if (this.state.userId !== '' && this.state.userId !== null) {....}
   ```
2. Recommended: Change method get_Id to arrow function signature:

   ```
   get_Id = async ()=> {
      try {
     const userId = await AsyncStorage.getItem('USER_ID') // (STORAGE_KEY)

     if (userId !== '' || userId !== null) {
       this.setState({ userId: userId })
       console.log('profile get_id id: =>', userId)
       // this.getUserDetails(userId)
     } else {
       console.log('profile get_id id: => user_id=null')
       Alert.alert('No user profile found LogIn Now ' + this.props.navigation.navigate('LogIn'))
     }

   } catch (error) {
     alert('Failed to load profile get_Id() user_id.')
   }
   ```

   }

Comment: thank you for your reply, your if condition is working but with a small change like this  `(this.state.userId != ''" && this.state.userId != null) {....},`

i used single not equal to instead of double not equal to,

Any way thank you sir .